# Change permissions for user connected to session

Tags: opentok, tokbox

When people initially connect to a live stream I only want them to be able to view the stream and send messages, but not publish their camera. Then I would like the moderator of the stream to be able to "grant them access" to be able to publish the camera. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenTok team replied to me via a support ticket:

> For publishing in the session after getting permission from the moderator, you need to use your own logic to restrict the user to publish until moderator approves, as the moderator privilege in Opentok only allows you to forceDisconnect any client from the session or forceUnpublish any publisher of a stream. More on moderation available here: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/moderation/js/